# Integral inequality for a Cauchy exponential series product

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

My goal is to get an inequality $\forall t>0$ for the following integral

$$
\int_0^t \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(-n^2 t_0)\right)^2\,\mathrm{d}t_0
\le f(t).
$$

The goal is to at least lose the the square of the series. Initially I thought it was possible to find a reasonable $f(t)$ using the Mean value theorem. However, there is not an easy upper-bound for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \exp(-n^2 t_0)$ since it explodes around $t_0 \approx 0$. Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your integral is $\infty$ whenever $t>0$. We get for $u>0$:
$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\exp(-n^2u)\right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\exp(-(n^2+m^2)u)$$
By the Fubini-Tonelli theorem we can exchange the order of integration and summation for a nonnegative function.  Fix $t>0$ and define $\mathcal{A}_t=\{(n,m)\in \mathbb{N}^2: (n^2+m^2)t\geq 1\}$. Then:
\begin{align} 
&\int_0^t  \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\exp(-n^2u)\right)^2 du \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\int_0^t \exp(-(n^2+m^2)u)du \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\exp(-t(n^2+m^2))}{n^2+m^2}\\
&\geq \sum_{(n,m)\in\mathcal{A}_t} \frac{1-\exp(-t(n^2+m^2))}{n^2+m^2}\\
&\geq (1-e^{-1})\sum_{(n,m)\in\mathcal{A}_t} \frac{1}{n^2+m^2}\\
&=\infty
\end{align}
where the final equality can be shown because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+m^2}=\infty$, and $\sum_{(n,m)\in\mathcal{A}_t}$ only neglects a finite number of terms in comparison to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: I do not think you did the expansion correct, since the correct Cauchy product expansion should be: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \exp((-m^2-(n-m)^2)t_0)$. This would lead to the integral result $\int_0^{t} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \exp((-m^2-(n-m)^2)t_0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{\exp((-m^2-(n-m)^2)t_0) - 1}{(-m^2-(n-m)^2}$.

Comment: @Amp : Why do you sum only from $m=1$ to $n-1$?

Comment: Excuse me, the integral should be $\int_0^{t} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \exp((-m^2-(n-m)^2)t_0) dt_0= \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{\exp((-m^2-(n-m)^2)t) - 1}{-m^2-(n-m)^2}$

Comment: I have used the Cauchy product rule here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Comment: Before integrating, you need a correct value of the double sum.

Comment: Why would the Cauchy product be inadequate here?

Comment: Any way you want to do the sum is fine. It looks like your way is more complicated, I cannot tell if you got the indexing correct or not.  It looks like your way is to fix the value of $l=n+m$ and then sum over all $(n,m)$ such that $n+m=l$.  This is essentially the same thing as just summing $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$. The Cauchy product rule does not contradict my summation.  If you want to double-check, you can verify $1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}$ and $1=1^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}2^{-m}$.

Comment: I agree. In that case I was already too severe because the above integral is already a result of an inequality. I need to go back to the drawing board. Thanks